# Cypress `.type` enters same text twice (duplicating each letter)

Tags: cypress

I have a cypress test that uses `cy.get(...).clear().type('some-text')`. When it runs, it *sometimes* works as expected, and *sometimes* enters `ssoommee--tteexxtt` instead of `some-text`. Yes, each letter is entered twice.  This seems to be happening roughly 50% of the time.

I have other tests that use `.type(...)`, none of which present this behavior. Only the first test using `.type(...)` does this.

Comment: "duplicated twice" is a duplicated meaning (pun intended), grammatically it's "duplicated" or  "typed twice".

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the surrounding tests, I found a stray `async` on the test right before the flaky one:

```
    it('Tests some element', async () => {
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.get('[id="some-element"]').should('exist')
    })
    
    it('Types into a text box', () => {
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.get('input[name="q"]').clear().type('some-text')
        ...
    })
```

That `async` on the previous test was the culprit! Removing it sorted it all out.